# GORM Updating multiple rows in the same query

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I am looking for the best way to update multiple rows of a table using gorm for Postgres.

```
type Info struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name  string
    Email string
}
```

I want to be able to update a slice of `Info` in a single transaction using gorm.

I am playing with transactions right now in this fashion but that doesn't seem to be robust

```
func UpdateInfos(ctx context.Context, db *gorm.DB, infos []Info) error {
    var err error
    tx := db.Begin()
    for _, info := range infos {
        tx.Model(&info).Where("id = ?", info.ID).Updates(info)
    }
    err = tx.Commit().Error
    return err
}
```

Would love to know if someone has found a solution to this sort of problem.

Comment: how does this work?, your `infos` variable is slice of `Info` struct which just contains `Name` and  `Email` and when you range over `infos` how come you get `info.ID`?

Comment: @0x4e696b68696c ID comes with struct embedding of `gorm.Model`

Answer (score 0):

gorm v1 does not support batch update. If you want to use gorm v1 and update multiple rows then you have to loop over the info slice.
gorm v2 has support for batch update. [Here is the documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Batch-Updates) for the same

Comment: Hi, it seems that the batch update in the docs applied to update multiple rows with the same data set. What if I need to batch update with different data for each rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can using Save Method

```
func UpdateInfos(ctx context.Context, db *gorm.DB, infos []Info) error {
    ...
    tx.Save(info)
    ...
    err = tx.Commit().Error
    return err
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your  answer doesn't have runnable code or any explanation, please edit it.